# Can I assign a hotkey to a cmd/Git Shell command?

Tags: git, cmd.exe

So I have a Git Shell that I use to compile stuff. Typical commands are:

```
cls ; make ; ./bin/Executable.exe
```

Is it possible to assign a certain hotkey to this command in the existing shell?

Answer (score 0):

When you're inside a `git`-repository, you can define aliases inside of `git`.  For example I have this in my `gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    show-graph = log --graph --abbrev-commit --oneline --decorate
```

Thus when calling `git show-graph --all` what is actually executed is `git log --graph --abbrev-commit --oneline --decorate --all`.  You cannot only abbreviate/alias `git` commands here, but you could also start the replacement with `!` and it would be treated as a shell-command, thus the following should work for you:

```
$ git config --local --add 'alias.build' '! cls; make; ./bin/Executable.exe'
$ git build
<should execute your command>
```

Comment: I was aware of aliases, I'm asking for a keybind possibility...